# Eliminación Registros Acumulados

Tags: sql, sql-server, delete

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server que utilizo para guardar datos de una sonda. Tengo ya muchos millones de registros y quiero dejar solamente un registro cada 30 minutos y eliminar los demás.

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:

[image: Tabla datos Sonda]

Al tener tantos registros en la tabla, necesito saber la forma más optima para hacer estas eliminacions.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crearte un evento en tu gestor de BDD: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

```html
CREATE EVENT borrarCadaMediaHora
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 30 MINUTE  
    DO
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM nombreTabla WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`fecha`) >= DATEADD(MM, -3, GETDATE());
 END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: el OP pregunta por SQL Server, no por MySQL

Comment: Corregido el enlace, para proceder a crear el evento.

Comment: Por otro lado, los históricos de los últimos 3 meses los quiero mantener. Solo quiero eliminar los registros de más de 3 meses.

Comment: Corregido, pero necesitas que los historicos sean los ultimos 3 meses con respecto a la fecha actual, o la fecha que guardas en la bdd?

Comment: Necesito eliminar los registros de la tabla y solo dejar uno cada 30 minutos. Esto solo para los registros de fecha de más de 90 días.

Comment: No estoy entendiendo que quieres hacer, quieres dejar un solo registro cada media hora, o borrar los registros que tienen más de 3 meses?

Comment: Necesitas explicitamente eliminar solo los registros que tengan mas de 3 meses de antiguedad?

Comment: Quiero dejar un solo registro cada media hora de los registros de más de tres meses